# How can I detect an element on the screen because sometimes it come with different formats using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to detect an element that can have different index on the screen, sometimes it can be detected like this `(//input[@value='OK'])[1]` and sometimes it appears and can be detected with this `(//input[@value='OK'])[2]` there is no other way to get this element to be unique because multiple elements are developed the same but every time it will appear with a different format, is there anyway to check whether it's detected by 1st or the 2nd index and then press on it. I tried try and catch but it's not working

```
try{
    while(true) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
                .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class, NoSuchElementException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(element))))
                .click();
    }
} catch (Exception ignored){ }
```

Comment: Please provide either the source-code of the wesite or the url.

Comment: If I understood your problem, each button can have same `classname` and `text` value, However there will be reference element against those elements and that should be unique. Please [Edit] your question and added text based html of multiple elements with parent node details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath1")).size()!=0)
{
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")).click
}
else if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath2")).size()!=0)
{
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath2")).click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigate to see if you can write relative xpath that is valid for both scenarios. Failing you can use an xpath conditional operator to combine the two values like `//*[@id='notify-containe' or contains(@id,'notify-container')]`.